# React Native error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I'm attempting to update a plugin for a react native project that was originally developed and worked in `0.40.0`.

Our current project is now on:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.0
```

In the code we have this method:

```
    private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                           String eventName,
                           @Nullable Object params) {
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(RCTNativeAppEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
    }
```

Which uses this import to get the Nullable class:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

The problem is that when we run `react-native run-android`

We get an error:

```
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
```

Any idea how I can get access to this Nullable class again or re-create the functionality such that I can pass in either a null field or like an int?

Examples of how I'd call it:

```
    public void UpdatePoints(int points) {
        sendEvent(this.reactContext, "UpdatePoints", points);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointsEarned() {
        sendEvent(this.reactContext, "onPointsEarned", null);
    }
```

I found another SO article that recommended this:

```
// build.gradle 
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"

// where use it
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

But that didn't work. I've found a few things mentioning a transition from support to androidX and it seems like this may be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you need to do is handle androidx by adding `import androidx.annotation.Nullable;` instead of `import android.support.annotation.Nullable;`